# How to properly disable checkboxes if number of maximum limit is reached?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here I have a different list of checkboxes `President` and `Senator` and all of the are generated from API result.
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLCbC.png)

For example in the `President` list the limit is 1 and if I selected/checked 1, the other checkboxes in the list will be disabled but when I deselect/uncheck and since the limit is not reached, the other checkboxes will be enabled again. How can I properly do that?

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('VOTE'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.check))
      ],
    ),
    body: Visibility(
      visible: isLoaded,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: positions?.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                      '${positions?[index].positionName} (Select - ${positions?[index].count})'),
                  for (var item in candidates!.where((candidate) =>
                      candidate.positionId == positions?[index].positionId))
                    CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text('${item.firstName}'),
                      subtitle: Text('${item.partyListName}'),
                      value: item.checkboxValue,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          item.checkboxValue = !item.checkboxValue!;
                          vote(item.candidateId);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
      replacement: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    ));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable like `allDisabled` and when one checkbox is checked, assign a null value to it as per the recommendation: [How to disable checkbox flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174090/how-to-disable-checkbox-flutter) or if there is a disabled property, assign true.

Docs for onChanged property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/onChanged.html